# Dynamic monthly excel calendar

Tags: microsoft-excel, calendar

I want to create a monthly calendar (1 month per sheet) where only the year could change (and so the date). My template of the calendar is already created. All I want is to add a formula that change the date according to the weekday when I change the year. The week starts on sunday

Thanks !

Comment: A copy or screenshot of your template would be useful. Also describe any existing formulas, and anything you've tried already. Seems like this should be doable, but would be very tricky. Is there any particular reason this needs to be in Excel, and not another application that's more particularly designed to handle calendars?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I've come up with. Adjust instructions as needed to fit your own template.

---

### Instructions

1. Set A1 to the value of the year for the month you want represented.

   - *For the date of this post's first revision, it would be "2015".*
2. Set A2 to the full name of the month you want represented.

   - *For the date of this post's first revision, it would be "May".*
3. Fill A3:G3 with the days of the week, starting with "Sunday" in A3 and ending with "Saturday" in G3.
4. Put the following formula in A4: `=IF(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE($A$2," 1, ",$A$1)))=1,1,"")`

   - *Depending on the Month/Year, this formula may return a blank value here. (It will for May 2015.) This is normal.*
5. Put the following formula in B4: `=IF(A4="",IF(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE($A$2," 1, ",$A$1)))=COLUMNS($A$4:B4),1,""),A4+1)`

   - *Depending on the Month/Year, this formula may return a blank value here. (It will for May 2015.) This is normal.*
6. Copy the formula from B4 across cells C4:G4. Excel should automatically adjust the cell references in the formula as needed.

   - *At this point, the formula should evaluate to "1" in one of the cells in row 4, and each cell afterward should return an increment higher than the previous cell. Cells before the "1" should be blank. For May 2015, you should see blanks in A4:E4, "1" in F4 (Friday), and "2" in G4 (Saturday)*.
7. Put the following formula in A5: `=IF(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE($A$2," ",G4+1,", ",$A$1))),"",G4+1)`

   - *The formula result should be one higher than the value of G4.*
8. Copy the formula in A5 down cells A6:A9. Excel should automatically adjust the cell references in the formula as needed.

   - *A6:A9 will evaluate to blanks for now. That is normal.*
9. Put the following formula in B5: `=IF(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE($A$2," ",A5+1,", ",$A$1))),"",A5+1)`

   - *The formula result should be one higher than the value of A5.*
10. Copy the formula in B5 across cells C5:G5. Excel should automatically adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

    - *Formulas in row 5 should now evaluate to a set of numbers increasing incrementally from column A to column G.*
11. Select B5:G5 and copy those cells down through B6:G9. Excel should automatically adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

    - *At this point, the calendar should be appropriately populated for the given month. Cells before the first of the month, and after the last day of the month, should be blank.*
    - *For certain months, such as January 2015, Row 9 will be entirely blank. This is normal.*

---

### Functions

- **CONCATENATE** joins text strings together.
- **DATEVALUE** returns an Excel "serial number" value for the date represented by a text string. It will return an error if the string does not match a known date format, or if the string does not represent an actual date (e.g.: "January 32, 2015" or "February 29, 2015").
- **WEEKDAY** returns a value, from 1 to 7, representing the weekday of a given date.
- **COLUMNS** returns the number of columns spanned by a specified array of cells.
- **IF** allows you to return a chosen value (or formula result) based on whether a specified formula evaluates to TRUE or FALSE.
- **ISERROR** returns TRUE if the given formula results in an error, or FALSE if the formula does not generate an error.

---

### Formula Explanations

- **A4** assembles information from A1 and A2 to generate a text string representing the first day of the month. (e.g.: "May 1, 2015".) Then, it checks to see if the weekday of that date would be Sunday. Returns 1 if it is a Sunday, blank if not.
- **B4:G4** check the preceding cell to see if it is blank. If not, returns a value one higher than the previous cell. If the previous cell is blank, checks to see if the current weekday matches the first day of the given month - returns 1 if so, blank if not.
- **A5:A9** add 1 to the value from the end of the preceding row, then combines the result with information from A1 and A2 to form a date string. Checks to see if the date actually exists. Returns the day-of-month number if so, blank if not.
- **B5:G9** add 1 to the value from preceding cell, then combines the result with information from A1 and A2 to form a date string. Checks to see if the date actually exists. Returns the day-of-month number if so, blank if not.

---

### Screenshot

Example output for May 2015.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create `New Workbook` from template. `Calendar sunday` search string.

[image: "Calendar sunday" search string]

Select **days area** and press `Manage Rules` in `Conditional Formatting` menu.

[image: edit Excel formatting rule menu]

Add `New Rule`

[image: Excel Rule formatting dialog]

Add rule equal `=TODAY()`

[image: Excell add formatting rule equal "=TODAY()"]

Result:

[image: Excel formatting rule Calendar result]

Comment: Ok, that's cheating. :-P

Comment: I like the simplicity for from-scratch operations but OP already has a template. If they can change it, then this is the way to go. If not, they'll need a formula approach.

Comment: @EngineerToast All may see formula at public template.

Answer (score 0):

Type these items into the indicated cells:

```
A1: 2015    B1: First day       C1: =DATEVALUE(A1&"-"&A2&"-01")
A2: 5       B2: Week-Sunday     C2: =C1-WEEKDAY(C1;2)

C4: =TEXT(COLUMNS($A$4:A4);"Ddd")
C5: =IF(TEXT($C$2-1+COLUMNS($A$4:A4)+(ROWS($A$4:A4)-1)*7;"YYYY-MM")=TEXT($C$1;"YYYY-MM");$C$2-1+COLUMNS($A$4:A4)+(ROWS($A$4:A4)-1)*7;"")
```

Then copy C4 and C5 to fill seven (7) cells width.
Followed by a copy of row 7 to fill a total of six (6) rows.
Select the cells in these last 6 rows and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, click Custom on the left panel and enter a single `D` for the custom format.

The result will look like this:

```
2015    First day   2015-05-01              
5       Week-Sunday 2015-04-26              

Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
                    1   2
3   4   5   6   7   8   9
10  11  12  13  14  15  16
17  18  19  20  21  22  23
24  25  26  27  28  29  30
31
```

This will work in Excel, LibreOffice and most likely any other spreadsheet.

Answer (score -1):

Linux:

Open a terminal, then type:

`ncal 2015` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (at the `$` prompt).

The output will look like:

```
                                  2015
    January           February          March             April             
Su     4 11 18 25     1  8 15 22        1  8 15 22 29        5 12 19 26   
Mo     5 12 19 26     2  9 16 23        2  9 16 23 30        6 13 20 27   
Tu     6 13 20 27     3 10 17 24        3 10 17 24 31        7 14 21 28   
We     7 14 21 28     4 11 18 25        4 11 18 25        1  8 15 22 29   
Th  1  8 15 22 29     5 12 19 26        5 12 19 26        2  9 16 23 30   
Fr  2  9 16 23 30     6 13 20 27        6 13 20 27        3 10 17 24      
Sa  3 10 17 24 31     7 14 21 28        7 14 21 28        4 11 18 25      

    May               June              July              August            
Su     3 10 17 24 31     7 14 21 28        5 12 19 26        2  9 16 23 30
Mo     4 11 18 25     1  8 15 22 29        6 13 20 27        3 10 17 24 31
Tu     5 12 19 26     2  9 16 23 30        7 14 21 28        4 11 18 25   
We     6 13 20 27     3 10 17 24        1  8 15 22 29        5 12 19 26   
Th     7 14 21 28     4 11 18 25        2  9 16 23 30        6 13 20 27   
Fr  1  8 15 22 29     5 12 19 26        3 10 17 24 31        7 14 21 28   
Sa  2  9 16 23 30     6 13 20 27        4 11 18 25        1  8 15 22 29   

    September         October           November          December          
Su     6 13 20 27        4 11 18 25     1  8 15 22 29        6 13 20 27   
Mo     7 14 21 28        5 12 19 26     2  9 16 23 30        7 14 21 28   
Tu  1  8 15 22 29        6 13 20 27     3 10 17 24        1  8 15 22 29   
We  2  9 16 23 30        7 14 21 28     4 11 18 25        2  9 16 23 30   
Th  3 10 17 24        1  8 15 22 29     5 12 19 26        3 10 17 24 31   
Fr  4 11 18 25        2  9 16 23 30     6 13 20 27        4 11 18 25      
Sa  5 12 19 26        3 10 17 24 31     7 14 21 28        5 12 19 26
```

... with current date marked with a "reversed block" number.
Copy and paste as text.
The amount of work required depends on the tool you use.

---

edit: Typing at the Bash shell prompt;
`$ y=2015; for (( i=1 ; i<13 ; i++)) do cal $i $y ; done | sed -re 's/([^ ]+ 2015|[a-zåäö]{2}|[ 0-9]{2} )/"\1",/g' | sed -re 's/"\,[ ]*$/"/' >calendar-$y.csv`

Creates a CSV-file that can be loaded into any Spreadsheet. change `y=2015` to reflect the year for which you wish create a calendar.

Comment: `for (( i=1 ; i<13 ; i++)) do cal $i 2015 ; done` creates a list of months instead of the table above. `man cal` for more options.

Comment: Nice, but the question was quite particularly about Excel. That means two things: 1. Chances are, the asker has some particular requirement to work in Excel, or is most comfortable using that tool. 2. The asker is probably on a Windows system - maybe Mac. Definitely not Linux.

Comment: For what it is worth: "Excel" to some is the same as "Spreadsheet", and there exists a number of variants of that.

Comment: Fair enough. But most of the same people think "Computer" == "Windows PC". ;-)

Comment: =) depends on who your mates are.